# Apache nutch is not crawling any more

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase, web-crawler, nutch

I have a two machine cluster. On one machine nutch is configured and on second hbase and hadoop are configured. hadoop is in fully distributed mode and hbase in pseudo distributed mode. I have crawled about 280GB data. But now when I start crawling . It gives following message and do not crawl any more in previous table

INFO  mapreduce.GoraRecordReader - gora.buffer.read.limit = 10000
INFO  crawl.FetchScheduleFactory - Using FetchSchedule impl: org.apache.nutch.crawl.DefaultFetchSchedule

and following bug

ERROR store.HBaseStore
 - [Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@7ae0c96b

Documents are fetched but they are not saved in hbase.
But if I crawl data in a new table, it works well and crawl properly witout any error. I think this is not a connection problem as for new table it works. I think it is bacause of some property etc.

Can anyone guide me as I am not an expert in apache nutch?

Comment: http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/Nutch2Tutorial?action=show&redirect=GORA_HBase

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a good place to ask Nutch question, send it in the maillist. In my impression, Nutch2.X is not as reliable as Nutch1.X.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I was also facing similiar problem. Actual problem was with regionserver (Hbase deamon ). So try to restart it as it is shutdown when used with default seeting and data is too mutch in hbase. For more information, see log files of regionserver.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite my field, but looks like thread exhaustion on the underlying machines.

Comment: I have to varify it before confirmation